# Programmatically change Google Voice forwarding settings

Tags: php, automation, google-voice

I've got an incredibly limited calling and data plan on my cell phone, and spend most of my waking hours in front of a computer with an Internet connection. With Google Voice able to route calls through Gmail, it seems silly to pay for minutes on my phone.

I'd like to use something like Tasker on my smartphone to change my Google Voice forwarding settings automatically so that calls are only routed to my cell phone when I'm not at a computer. The trigger rules are simple enough, but Google Voice doesn't have any official API for things like this.

Has anyone had any success with changing Google Voice settings via some hacked-up API? I've seen a couple that do things like place calls and send SMS messages, but all I need is to change settings, which the ones I saw didn't support. Perhaps a little documentation on how Google Voice handles web requests currently that I could use to change things from a PHP script that I could then call from my phone?

Bonus points if I can use some sort of long-lasting login token rather than having to store my Google password in cleartext.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution? I have written a Google Voice API in PHP https://github.com/hbattat/GeeVeeAPI and would be happy to add a function that does changes the forwarding settings for you.

Comment: I've worked around the issue using something completely unrelated, but if you can provide an example using your class that solves the original problem, I'd be happy to accept it. An API that handles settings changes would be really cool.